# How to extract year from a dates cell array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

i have a cell array as below, which are dates. I am wondering how can i extract the year at the last 4 digits? Could anyone teach me how to locate the year in the string? Thank you!

```
'31.12.2001'
'31.12.2000'
'31.12.2004'
'31.12.2003'
'31.12.2002'
'31.12.2000'
'31.12.1999'
'31.12.1998'
'31.12.1997'
'31.12.2005'
'31.12.2004'
'31.12.2003'
'31.12.2002'
'31.12.2001'
'31.12.2000'
'31.12.1999'
'31.12.1998'
'31.12.2005'
'31.12.2004'
'31.12.2003'
'31.12.2002'
'31.12.2005'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example cell array:

```
A = {'31.12.2001'; '31.12.2002'; '31.12.2003'};
```

Apply some regular expressions:

```
B = regexp(A, '\d\d\d\d', 'match')
B = [B{:}];
```

**EDIT:** I never realized that matlab will "nest" an extra layer of cells until I tested this. I don't like this solution as much now that I know the second line is necessary. Here is an alternative approach that gets you the years in numeric form:

```
C = datevec(A, 'dd.mm.yyyy');
C = C(:, 1);
```

**SECOND EDIT:** Suprisingly, if your cell array has less than 10000 elements, the `regexp` approach is faster on my machine. But the output of it is another cell array (which takes up much more memory than a numeric matrix). You can use `B = cell2mat(B)` to get a character array instead, but this brings the two approaches to approximately equal efficiency.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have heard that some ppl use 'sscanf' to do this. But when i check the help mannual for this command, i am totally lost. Could you tell me how to use 'sscanf' to handle this situation?

Comment: @Flyingpig Not sure off the top of my head and I don't have access to Matlab for a while. I do know that `sscanf` will not operate on cell arrays, so you'll need to convert it to a character array first using `char(A)`. However, once you've got a character array it makes much more sense to just use linear indexing as in Rody's or Dennis's answer, rather than messing around with `sscanf`. So I can pretty confidently say that `sscanf` is not the right tool for this particular job.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a fun answer, designed to take the OP to the stranger regions of Matlab:

```
C = char(C);
y = (D(:,7:end)-'0') * 10.^(3:-1:0).'
```

which is an order of magnitude faster than anything posted in the other answers :)

Or, to stay a bit closer to home,

```
y = cellfun(@(x)str2double(x(7:end)),C);
```

or, yet another `regexp` variation:

```
y = str2num(char(regexprep(C, '\d+\.\d+\.','')));
```

Comment: I had to go through that second line piece by piece to work out what was going on. Pure magic.

Comment: It is brittle with respect to format, if I understand correctly, but nice.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your matrix with dates is M or a cell array C:

In case your data is in a cell array start with

```
M = cell2mat(C)
```

Then get the relevant part

```
Y=M(:,end-4:end)
```

If required you can even make the year a number

```
Year = str2num(Y)
```

Comment: This will only work with a character array, not a cell array.

Comment: Updated, now it is a bit more general and still quite robust

Answer (score 1):

Using regexp this will works also with dates with slightly different formats, like `1.1.2000`, which can mess with you offsets

```
res = regexp(dates, '(?<=\d+\.\d+\.)\d+', 'match')
```